# Abort AJAX and form submitions, save them, change them, and send it later

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I need to request additional credentials to a user when he clicks certain buttons and submits certain forms.

I way I am trying to do it is:

- Intercept the submit event, abort it, and store a copy
- Ask for the credentials with an prompt dialog (not the JS native one, so this is all non-blocking)
- If user inputs the credentials, insert the fields into the event data and send it to the server.

My current code for AJAX requests is:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
  if (ajaxOptions.type === "POST") {
    $.current_request = jqXHR;
    jqXHR.abort();
    $.check_password_with_my_dialog();
  }
});

$.check_password_with_my_dialog: function() {
  $("#validate-password-prompt").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "input pw",
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $.password = $("#validate-password-prompt input").val();
        $.deliver_current_request();
        return $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        return $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
}

deliver_current_request: function() {
  $.current_request.beforeSend = function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    ajaxOptions.data = ajaxOptions.data.concat("&password=" + $.password);
  };
  $.ajax($.current_request);
}
```

The problem so far is that `ajaxOptions.data` is undefined, so I can't add my data.
And the requests seems to be going as a GET instead of POST.

Am I doing this the right way, or am I way of?

Comment: One way is,
when the user submits the form, first get the password using modal before actually submitting form.
and if he enters a password, then append the password to the serialized form data and submit the form through ajax post.
else if he cancel the password model, then simply quit or save the serialized data in local memory and use it for further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**

Here is a way i can think of to accomplish answer for your question.

```
<form id="myForm" >
  <button id="submit-form-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="validate-admin-password-prompt">
    <input type="password"/>
</div>
```

In javascript,

```
function submitForm(pwd) {
    var formData = $('form#myForm').serialize() + "&password=" + pwd;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://google.com",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "script"
    });
    alert("POSTed: " + formData.toString());
}

function alertDialog() {
  $("#validate-admin-password-prompt").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Admin password is required",
    zIndex: 10000,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        var pwd = $("#validate-admin-password-prompt input").val();
        submitForm(pwd);
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        alert('Not authorized to submit the form');
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
}
$("#submit-form-btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $ele = $("#validate-admin-password-prompt input");    
  if ($ele.val()==null || $ele.val().trim()=="") {
      alertDialog();
  } else {
      submitForm($ele.val());
  }
});
```

Comment: It won't work because opening the modal is a non-blocking operation.
The code will continue to execute and reach the else case.

Comment: can i know what exactly non-blocking operation means?

Comment: means that the code will continue to execute instead of waiting for the hole function that 1- opens the modal; 2-waits for user input; 3-validate user input; 4- returns.
Therefor, I cannot inject the password into the form data, because by the time I get the password, the form was already submitted. (in your code it would reach the else condition because pwd would evaluate to undefined)

Comment: i think the form will not submit, because we have written 'e.preventDefault();'statement which will prevent the default behavior of button.

Comment: How about this?? can you run this and let me know is this what you needed?
http://jsfiddle.net/zSmhu/2/

Comment: Yes that is correct, but, unfortunately it is not my case because I need this feature to be as generic as possible, so that `submitForm(pwd);` can be any function. I got it working, through a similar method ;)

Comment: To make it more generic, still you can pass url as a parameter. submitForm(url, pwd); And glad that you able to got the solution. :)